# Excel Pivot Chart 'fixed' horizontal axis

Tags: excel, powerpivot, axis-labels, pivot-chart

I have got a horizontal axis that holds numbers (roughly 7,5 through 18 at 0,5 intervals) based on the set filters.

I would like it to always show the 7,5 though 18 on the horizontal axis, even if the filtered only is applicable 10 to 12,5 for example.

Thing is, the axis options do not show bounds to set as I have found to appear in other solutions:

[image]

I've double checked to make sure my axis data is formated as numbers:

[image]

In case of possible relevancy, the formula used to calculate the day time indicator is

```
=mround((mod(GDQ[Timestamp];1)*24);0,5)
```

Is there a way to have the horizontal axis always show start through end plotting the filtered data always on the same timeframe?

Comment: I'm gonna take a shot here and say that it can't be done, as the x axis data points are categorical in nature - I don't see any option to set a min/max for those points in Excel 2016, but I could be totally wrong.

Comment: But even then, there should be an option to fixed set of categories I can fill in, not?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "to fixed set of categories I can fill in"?

Comment: If I cannot trick Excel into setting a minnmax range for the numbers to display, can I enter a set to always display along the axis? So instead of mine 7,5 max 18, I would just enter my intervals as categories for it to plot against?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 2):

I had exactly the same issue, and solved it on the pivot table side.
Go to the field setting (in your case for the day/time indicator, your x-axis), then to the tab  "Layout & Print", and activate "Show items with no data".

Now every category will always show up in the pivot table, even with no data after you do some filtering with your slicer, and the layout of the graph will remain constant (axis limits).

Comment: Welcome to SO!. Good answer! Please avoid adding noise in your post. There is no need to add a signature at the bottom of your answer. You may edit your profile and add more info there. Whoever is interested, can simply click your username. A more comprehensive DOs and DON'Ts here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and was saved by the above answer!

Just to expand on the answer above, after ticking the "show items with no data" box in the field settings, if you also go into the pivot chart options and change "for empty cells show:" to '0', it will connect the empty data points at zero on the y axis which makes for a much nicer look.

Comment: this should move to be a comment